# Send Link to verify users registration

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

How can I force the users to click on the registration link send on email, in order to be members.
I alrerady send this link on the email of the new user by he doesnt need to click on it. He can directly connect with his email and password created

```
  fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    // send verification link
                    FirebaseUser fuser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    fuser.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> Toast.makeText(Register.this, "La vérification de l'email a été envoyée.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()).addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.d(TAG, "Echec: Email non envoyé " + e.getMessage()));

                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Compte créé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);
                    Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                    user.put("fName",fullName);
                    user.put("email",email);
                    user.put("phone",phone);
                    documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> Log.d(TAG, "Succès: profil utilisateur crée pour "+ userID)).addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.d(TAG, "échec" + e.toString()));
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Erreur ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a function to check if the email is verified or not and only then start the activity like this

```
private void IsEmailVerified() {
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (user.isEmailVerified()) {
           Log.d("verified", "Email is verified.");
    } else {
          Log.d("verified", "Email is not verified !.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where Do I write this function in my code to be sur that it will work?

Comment: create this function in your activity. Then in your sign in function call this function when user successfully signs in. If user email is verified then only start your next activity, else prompt a dialog or toast asking them to verify